# How to hide "showInLegend" of Highcharts in angular 8.1?

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I would like to toggle(hide and show) the legend of pie chart in highcharts by the click of a button.
I'm using angular 8.1 with highcharts-angular wrap.

Here's the code:

.ts file

```
highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartOptions = {   
    chart: {
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBorderWidth: null,
      plotShadow: false,
      type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            showInLegend: true
        }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Brands',
      colorByPoint: true,
      data: [{
          name: 'Chrome',
          y: 61.41,
      }, {
          name: 'Internet Explorer',
          y: 11.84
      }, {
          name: 'Firefox',
          y: 10.85
      }, {
          name: 'Edge',
          y: 4.67
      }, {
          name: 'Safari',
          y: 4.18
      }, {
          name: 'Other',
          y: 7.05
      }]
    }]
  };

  constructor() { }


  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onToggleLegend() {
    console.log('legend is toggled!');
    this.chartOptions.plotOptions.pie.showInLegend = 
     !this.chartOptions.plotOptions.pie.showInLegend;
  }
}
```

.html file

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col s12">
         <highcharts-chart
            [Highcharts] = "highcharts" 
            [options] = "chartOptions">
         </highcharts-chart>
   </div>
   <button (click)="onToggleLegend()">Toggle Legend</button>
</div>
```

When I click on the Toggle button the message 'legend is toggled!' is displayed but the legend in the pie chart doesnot toggle. It is always visible.

Comment: Can you share stackbiltz

Comment: stackbiltz link: https://stackblitz.com/github/shadabumer/materializeCharts

Comment: please check the pie-chart folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are mutate an object, there for Angular does not know its properties changed.

To fix the problem, we can reassign to new object like this:

```
onToggleLegend() {
    console.log('legend is toggled!');
    this.chartOptions.plotOptions.pie.showInLegend = !this.chartOptions.plotOptions.pie.showInLegend;
    console.log(this.chartOptions.plotOptions.pie.showInLegend)

    this.chartOptions = {
      ...this.chartOptions
    }
  }
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-sgujxk?file=src/app/pie-chart/pie-chart.component.ts

By reassign, we create new object, so Angular will run Change Detection process.

You can read more about **Immutability** from this article

https://vsavkin.com/immutability-vs-encapsulation-90549ab74487

Comment: solution what you gave works perfectly, but I don't understand the logic. Could you please explain more or provide a link for any related resource

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {},
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            margin: 60
        }
   },

    legend: {
        enabled: true,
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29900, 71500, 106400, 129200, 144000, 176000, 135600, 148500, 216400, 194100, 95600, 54400]
    }]
},function(chart){

    $('#updateLegend').click(function (e) {
        var legend = chart.legend; 

        if(legend.display) {
            legend.group.hide();
            legend.box.hide();
            legend.display = false;
        } else {

            legend.group.show();
            legend.box.show();
            legend.display = true;
        }
    });
});
```

I think you got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by hiding the svg legend group like that:

```
  onToggleLegend() {
    if (this.legendVisible) {
      this.chartRef.legend.group.hide();
      this.legendVisible = false;
    } else {
      this.chartRef.legend.group.show();
      this.legendVisible = true;
    }
  }
```

Note, that `this.chartRef` is a reference to the chart object and can be saved in Angular using this piece of code:

```
chartOptions = {
  chart: {
    ...
    events: {
      load: (function(self) {
        return function() {
          self.chartRef = this;
        }
      })(this)
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-baf3te?file=src/app/pie-chart/pie-chart.component.ts

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#hide
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#show